# Can't visualize sensor data using Bluemix IoT Foundation

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

When trying to use the [recipe](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/visualizing-your-data/) to visualize data from my device which is registered to the IoT Foundation  I am not seeing any data on the graph.

When I try and publish the following:

```
myData={'name' : 'RPi', 'temp' : temp, 'relh' : relh}
```

... I get a blank visualization 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the data in JSON format (the visualization displays numerical data):

```
myData={'d': {'size': 54, 'temp': 34}}
```

Documentation on this format can be found here: https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/messaging/payload.html